# A period must not appear consecutively in a String Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a code check if the user input is valid in the regular expression pattern. The patter is @ the problem is how to check if the character . appears consecutively

[a-z|A-Z|0-9|[.]{1}]+@[[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+ 
i've tried this patter so far.

```
    System.out.print("Enter your Email: ");
    String userInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[a-z|A-Z|0-9|[.]{1}]+@[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(userInput);

    if(mat.matches()){
        System.out.print("Valid");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Invalid");
    }

}
```

}

if the input is een..123@asd123
I expect the output will Invalid but if the input is een.123@asd123 the output will Valid

Comment: `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]` is wrong. You don't need the `|` in a character class. Change to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: `indexOf("..") == -1`.

Comment: `^(\w+\.?)+\w+@\w+$` if you want underscore, else just replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: Please reword your question. If you do not want consecutive .'s, use one of the very simple regexes provided. If you are validating an email address, this is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want consecutive periods, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`

*Explanation*

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+      Match one or more letters or digits
(?:               Start non-capturing group
   \.               Match exactly one period
   [a-zA-Z0-9]+     Match one or more letters or digits
)*                End optional repeating group
```

With this pattern, the value cannot start or end with a period, and cannot have consecutive periods.

---

Alternatively, use a negative lookahead: `(?!.*[.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

*Explanation*

```
(?!.*[.]{2})                 Fail match if 2 consecutive periods are found
[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+   Match normally
```

Answer (score 1):

A character class matches any of the listed characters. If you specify a pipe `|` that does not mean `OR` but it could then also match a `|`.

If you don't want to match consecutive dots, you could make use of a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that does not contain a dot, and then use a quantifier to repeat a grouping structure that does start with a dot.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any character that is listed in the charater class
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times a group which starts with a dot and matches 1+ times what is listed in the character class to prevent consecutive dots.
- `@` Match @ char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match again 1+ chars
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Match again repeating group
- `$` End of string

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/06WDIi/1)